# why is my mesh not moving correctly with weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

here is my an image of my mesh. [image]

For some strange reason i red weight paint is not working. how can i fix thi

Comment: Yes, sometimes the Automatic weights creates issues and don't work properly. Most of the time I have to go over each automatic weighted vertex group and modify it to work the way I intended. Happy Blendering,

Comment: You should check each vertex groups directly if you can. While doing a project my problem was the weights were added. Ex: the left feet's weight were mixed with right so I had to paint the left feet's weight influence to zero for the right

Answer (score -1):

I Managed to find a solution.

Go into 'object mode' select the figure mesh(not the armature), and look at the vertex groups assign to that specific mesh. My problem was that my vertex groups were all out of alignment (The vertices were spread in placed i didnt intend to put).

So i deleted all of my Vertex groups, and stated assigning new one with the correct vertices.